# Undefined method 'update_attributes' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm trying to update_attributes with this private method and due to the association, i thought i could call `cart.update_attributes` but for some reason, it is returning an undefined method. Someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

```
class PaymentNotification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cart
  serialize :params
  after_create :mark_cart_as_purchased


 private

  def mark_cart_as_purchased
    if status == "Completed"
      cart.update_attribute(:purchased_at, Time.now)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your cart object is nil.

Comment: @Rog Yeah, but because of the association, it shouldn't be. Right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Just because you have an association is doesn't mean it exists, it only means it can exist. If you want a cart you need to create one first.

Comment: @Rails_learner No, it will be nil unless you've actually associated your payment with a cart, either by `@cart.create_payment` or `@payment.cart = @cart`, or use a similar method to create the association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cart` association isn't necessarily defined in your code, so it will return nil if the `cart_id` is nil or doesn't reference a valid cart. You should probably add a presence validation for it, or guard against updating the card attribute if it's not present:

```
after_create :mark_cart_as_purchased, if: -> { cart.present? }
```